# Kotlin coroutines - RunBlocking freezes on exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to coroutines in Kotlin, and I ran into a really weird condition. I created a function similar to this:

```
fun doStuff() {
    runBlocking {
        (0 until configurableLimit)
            .map { index -> 
                async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    // Code that throws exception
                }
            }
            .awaitAll()
        println("Complete")
    }
}
```

The goal, obviously, was to run a series of tasks in parallel and wait for them all to complete. However, when I ran this the application would just freeze, the tasks would never complete, and there was no information about why this was happening.

After further investigation, I learned that the code within the async() block was failing with an exception (I ran the code without the coroutine piece to learn that). However, there was no exception appearing in the logs.

Finally, I changed runBlocking to launch:

```
fun doStuff() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        (0 until configurableLimit)
            .map { index -> 
                async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    // Code that throws exception
                }
            }
            .awaitAll()
        println("Complete")
    }
}
```

Now, the code in the async() block was still failing, but the exception was now being propagated and showing up in the logs. At which point I fixed the underlying problem and everything worked perfectly.

My concern here is that I don't understand the weird exception behavior that I encountered with runBlocking. It really doesn't make any sense to me. What might have happened there?

Comment: I believe your code should work as you expect. I tested it and `doStuff()` didn't freeze, but resulted in an exception. Is there a possibility that you run `runBlocking()` inside another `runBlocking()`?

Comment: Also, how do you observe that it freezes and not throws? Maybe you just accidentally catch the exception somewhere along the call stack?